# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest polyfill

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm doing an experiment to see if I can replace function bodies with synchronous ajax calls that get eval'd

I'm aware that they are deprecated and that its a bad idea to use them, but I can't think of another way to do this.

Is there a way to make async ajax calls synchronous?

I've tried using `while (request.readyState !==);` 
but that seems to block the request as well

Comment: `xhr.open("GET","path/to/file.ext",false);`

Comment: `document.write("<script src=...">)` is also sync, but only works during load.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<script>
document.write("<script src=/path/to/your/js/file.js><\/script>")
</script>
```

or better yet use

```
<script src=/path/to/your/js/file.js></script>
```

That code will be loaded and executed before any further code execution on the page.